# Which INSERT is faster: with VALUES or with SELECT/UNION ALL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Which INSERT statement with multiple rows is faster in SQL Server?

This?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (ID, Name)
SELECT 123, 'Timmy' UNION ALL
SELECT 124, 'Jonny' UNION ALL
...
SELECT 925, 'Sally'
```

Or this?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (ID, Name) VALUES
(123, 'Timmy'),
(124, 'Jonny'),
...
(925, 'Sally')
```

---

I tried to record `18704` rows using one `INSERT` for each `10` rows. *Times are in (mm:ss)*

- `SELECT/UNION ALL` solution took `25:37`
- `VALUES` solution took `27:26`

It was unexpected, because I hoped the `SELECT/UNION ALL` solution would be slower as it was more explicit operation (`SELECT` and `UNION ALL`).

Notably this performance is not good as it could be and surely the bottleneck is another thing, but I'd like to know if there is a significant difference between this two forms.

Comment: What have you observed during your tests? [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) and report back your findings and please, elaborate your response.

Comment: I tried to record 18704 rows using one insert for each 10 rows. The SELECT/UNION ALL solution took 25min37s and VALUES solution took 27min26s. It was unexpected, because I hoped the SELECT/UNION ALL solution would be slower as it was more explicit operation (SELECT and UNION ALL).

Comment: `VALUES` is shorter syntax. And for 18704 rows you better use a load utility. Btw, it's a lot to parse when you submit those 18704 rows in a single statement.

Comment: @VictorF for 20k rows? That is terrible performance. Do you have a trigger on that table?

Comment: *  'Race your horses' just gave me a Roseanne Roseannadanna flashback ..  :: snicker ::

Comment: 25+ minutes for an insert of two fields with 18k rows? Surely there is something else at play. I'm with @UnhandledExcepSean check for triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance difference is going to very minor.  You should not be worrying about such things.

It is possibly faster to `bulk insert` the data.

If your insert is taking that long, then you have other problems, most likely:

- Contention on the table (the table is locked by other processes).
- Triggers on the table.
- *A lot* of index overhead.
- Check constraints using complex user-defined functions.

You might just have lots of contention on the table from other processes.

You might want to split the `insert` into smaller chunks.  This will incur less contention.